# ArangoDB AQL is affected by the injection issue?

Tags: code-injection, arangodb, aql

I'm working with AQL in these days, and I'm creating a library for dynamically creating the AQL script.

Because I didn't find anything related to the PARAMETER INJECTION issue (like SQL INJECTION) do you think that is secure if I set my FILTER variable directly inside the AQL query string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using bindParameters for all user-defined input the value inserted will not be evaluated by the AQL parser and hence injected code will not be executed.

Safe query:

```
FOR x IN items FILTER x.name == @name RETURN x
```

Unsafe query:

```
"FOR x IN items FILTER x.name == " + name + " RETURN x"
```

Inserting sth. like

```
'a' LET t = (FOR h IN items DELETE h)
```

in name will return all elements having exactly this string in the save query (not harmful).
In the unsafe query it will drop all elements in items (harmful).

Comment: Thank for your answer @mchacki; it is not completely clear what do you mean. The first two examples are fine, but not the last one. However, I will look for bind parameters with .NET Driver :)

Comment: The last one is no direct AQL. It is an AQL snippet that, injected into the right place, does evil things (emptying your collection). If you put that together the save query will search for documents like `{name :"'a' LET t = (FOR h IN items DELETE h)"}`. With the unsafe query you get a completely different AQL: `FOR x IN items FILTER x.name == 'a' LET t = (FOR h IN items DELETE h)  RETURN x` which will execute the Subquery with DELETE if there is any element with `{name: "a"}` stored.

Comment: Has the additional `@` for collection placeholders something do to with injection prevention as well? (`FOR doc IN @@coll RETURN doc`, `{"@coll": "test"}`)

Comment: It partly has to do something with injection prevention. Using one @ will interpret the value as a plain string. using @@ will search of a collection with this exact name. So you cannot inject collection names where they are not supposed to be and the server can early reject if you try to access something that is not a collection.